# Highcharts Issue in drilldown in dual axis eg. Bellcurve Chart etc

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, drilldown

In a dual axis chart on a point drill down I am still able to see the bellcurve which was on the first level. Is this the expected behavior if yes then how can I stop showing the parent series on drilldown. In case of no, let me know how can i fix this.  Please see this fiddle for the issue.

In case of dual x and y axis chart example something weird happens on the drilldown & I see the non parent series after drilldown.

Dual X and Y axis drilldown issue : https://jsfiddle.net/p6cz7Lk1/1/

Please see this fiddle for the bellcurve issue.
https://jsfiddle.net/6f379jw4/4/

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  title: {
    text: 'Bell curve'
  },

  xAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: 'Data'
    },
    alignTicks: false
  }, {
    title: {
      text: 'Bell curve'
    },
    alignTicks: false,
    opposite: true
  }],

  yAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: 'Data'
    }
  }, {
    title: {
      text: 'Bell curve'
    },
    opposite: true
  }],

  series: [{
    name: 'Bell curve',
    type: 'bellcurve',
    xAxis: 1,
    yAxis: 1,
    baseSeries: 1,
    zIndex: -1
  }, {
    name: 'Data',
    type: 'scatter',
    data: [
    {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 3.5,
        drilldown: "Chrome"
      },
      {
        "x": 0.5,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 3.2
      },
      {
        "x": 1.5,
        "y": 3.1
      },
      {
        "x": 2,
        "y": 3.6
      },
      {
        "x": 2.5,
        "y": 3.9
      },
      {
        "x": 3,
        "y": 3.4
      },
      {
        "x": 3.5,
        "y": 3.4
      },
      {
        "x": 4,
        "y": 2.9
      },
      {
        "x": 4.5,
        "y": 3.1
      },
      {
        "x": 5,
        "y": 3.7
      },
      {
        "x": 5.5,
        "y": 3.4
      },
      {
        "x": 6,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 6.5,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 7,
        "y": 4
      },
      {
        "x": 7.5,
        "y": 4.4
      },
      {
        "x": 8,
        "y": 3.9
      },
      {
        "x": 8.5,
        "y": 3.5
      },
      {
        "x": 9,
        "y": 3.8
      },
      {
        "x": 9.5,
        "y": 3.8
      },
      {
        "x": 10,
        "y": 3.4
      },
      {
        "x": 10.5,
        "y": 3.7
      },
      {
        "x": 11,
        "y": 3.6
      },
      {
        "x": 11.5,
        "y": 3.3
      },
      {
        "x": 12,
        "y": 3.4
      },
      {
        "x": 12.5,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 13,
        "y": 3.4
      },
      {
        "x": 13.5,
        "y": 3.5
      },
      {
        "x": 14,
        "y": 3.4
      },
      {
        "x": 14.5,
        "y": 3.2
      },
      {
        "x": 15,
        "y": 3.1
      },
      {
        "x": 15.5,
        "y": 3.4
      },
      {
        "x": 16,
        "y": 4.1
      },
      {
        "x": 16.5,
        "y": 4.2
      },
      {
        "x": 17,
        "y": 3.1
      },
      {
        "x": 17.5,
        "y": 3.2
      },
      {
        "x": 18,
        "y": 3.5
      },
      {
        "x": 18.5,
        "y": 3.6
      },
      {
        "x": 19,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 19.5,
        "y": 3.4
      },
      {
        "x": 20,
        "y": 3.5
      },
      {
        "x": 20.5,
        "y": 2.3
      },
      {
        "x": 21,
        "y": 3.2
      },
      {
        "x": 21.5,
        "y": 3.5
      },
      {
        "x": 22,
        "y": 3.8
      },
      {
        "x": 22.5,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 23,
        "y": 3.8
      },
      {
        "x": 23.5,
        "y": 3.2
      },
      {
        "x": 24,
        "y": 3.7
      },
      {
        "x": 24.5,
        "y": 3.3
      },
      {
        "x": 25,
        "y": 3.2
      },
      {
        "x": 25.5,
        "y": 3.2
      },
      {
        "x": 26,
        "y": 3.1
      },
      {
        "x": 26.5,
        "y": 2.3
      },
      {
        "x": 27,
        "y": 2.8
      },
      {
        "x": 27.5,
        "y": 2.8
      },
      {
        "x": 28,
        "y": 3.3
      },
      {
        "x": 28.5,
        "y": 2.4
      },
      {
        "x": 29,
        "y": 2.9
      },
      {
        "x": 29.5,
        "y": 2.7
      },
      {
        "x": 30,
        "y": 2
      },
      {
        "x": 30.5,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 31,
        "y": 2.2
      },
      {
        "x": 31.5,
        "y": 2.9
      },
      {
        "x": 32,
        "y": 2.9
      },
      {
        "x": 32.5,
        "y": 3.1
      },
      {
        "x": 33,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 33.5,
        "y": 2.7
      },
      {
        "x": 34,
        "y": 2.2
      },
      {
        "x": 34.5,
        "y": 2.5
      },
      {
        "x": 35,
        "y": 3.2
      },
      {
        "x": 35.5,
        "y": 2.8
      },
      {
        "x": 36,
        "y": 2.5
      },
      {
        "x": 36.5,
        "y": 2.8
      },
      {
        "x": 37,
        "y": 2.9
      },
      {
        "x": 37.5,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 38,
        "y": 2.8
      },
      {
        "x": 38.5,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 39,
        "y": 2.9
      },
      {
        "x": 39.5,
        "y": 2.6
      },
      {
        "x": 40,
        "y": 2.4
      },
      {
        "x": 40.5,
        "y": 2.4
      },
      {
        "x": 41,
        "y": 2.7
      },
      {
        "x": 41.5,
        "y": 2.7
      },
      {
        "x": 42,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 42.5,
        "y": 3.4
      },
      {
        "x": 43,
        "y": 3.1
      },
      {
        "x": 43.5,
        "y": 2.3
      },
      {
        "x": 44,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 44.5,
        "y": 2.5
      },
      {
        "x": 45,
        "y": 2.6
      },
      {
        "x": 45.5,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 46,
        "y": 2.6
      },
      {
        "x": 46.5,
        "y": 2.3
      },
      {
        "x": 47,
        "y": 2.7
      },
      {
        "x": 47.5,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 48,
        "y": 2.9
      },
      {
        "x": 48.5,
        "y": 2.9
      },
      {
        "x": 49,
        "y": 2.5
      },
      {
        "x": 49.5,
        "y": 2.8
      },
      {
        "x": 50,
        "y": 3.3
      },
      {
        "x": 50.5,
        "y": 2.7
      },
      {
        "x": 51,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 51.5,
        "y": 2.9
      },
      {
        "x": 52,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 52.5,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 53,
        "y": 2.5
      },
      {
        "x": 53.5,
        "y": 2.9
      },
      {
        "x": 54,
        "y": 2.5
      },
      {
        "x": 54.5,
        "y": 3.6
      },
      {
        "x": 55,
        "y": 3.2
      },
      {
        "x": 55.5,
        "y": 2.7
      },
      {
        "x": 56,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 56.5,
        "y": 2.5
      },
      {
        "x": 57,
        "y": 2.8
      },
      {
        "x": 57.5,
        "y": 3.2
      },
      {
        "x": 58,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 58.5,
        "y": 3.8
      },
      {
        "x": 59,
        "y": 2.6
      },
      {
        "x": 59.5,
        "y": 2.2
      },
      {
        "x": 60,
        "y": 3.2
      },
      {
        "x": 60.5,
        "y": 2.8
      },
      {
        "x": 61,
        "y": 2.8
      },
      {
        "x": 61.5,
        "y": 2.7
      },
      {
        "x": 62,
        "y": 3.3
      },
      {
        "x": 62.5,
        "y": 3.2
      },
      {
        "x": 63,
        "y": 2.8
      },
      {
        "x": 63.5,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 64,
        "y": 2.8
      },
      {
        "x": 64.5,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 65,
        "y": 2.8
      },
      {
        "x": 65.5,
        "y": 3.8
      },
      {
        "x": 66,
        "y": 2.8
      },
      {
        "x": 66.5,
        "y": 2.8
      },
      {
        "x": 67,
        "y": 2.6
      },
      {
        "x": 67.5,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 68,
        "y": 3.4
      },
      {
        "x": 68.5,
        "y": 3.1
      },
      {
        "x": 69,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 69.5,
        "y": 3.1
      },
      {
        "x": 70,
        "y": 3.1
      },
      {
        "x": 70.5,
        "y": 3.1
      },
      {
        "x": 71,
        "y": 2.7
      },
      {
        "x": 71.5,
        "y": 3.2
      },
      {
        "x": 72,
        "y": 3.3
      },
      {
        "x": 72.5,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 73,
        "y": 2.5
      },
      {
        "x": 73.5,
        "y": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 74,
        "y": 3.4
      },
      {
        "x": 74.5,
        "y": 3
      }
    ],
    accessibility: {
      exposeAsGroupOnly: true
    },
    marker: {
      radius: 1.5
    }
  }],
  drilldown: {
    series: [{
        name: "Chrome",
        id: "Chrome",
        data: [
          [
            "v65.0",
            0.1
          ],
          [
            "v64.0",
            1.3
          ],
          [
            "v63.0",
            53.02
          ],
          [
            "v62.0",
            1.4
          ],
          [
            "v61.0",
            0.88
          ],
          [
            "v60.0",
            0.56
          ],
          [
            "v59.0",
            0.45
          ],
          [
            "v58.0",
            0.49
          ],
          [
            "v57.0",
            0.32
          ],
          [
            "v56.0",
            0.29
          ],
          [
            "v55.0",
            0.79
          ],
          [
            "v54.0",
            0.18
          ],
          [
            "v51.0",
            0.13
          ],
          [
            "v49.0",
            2.16
          ],
          [
            "v48.0",
            0.13
          ],
          [
            "v47.0",
            0.11
          ],
          [
            "v43.0",
            0.17
          ],
          [
            "v29.0",
            0.26
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Firefox",
        id: "Firefox",
        data: [
          [
            "v58.0",
            1.02
          ],
          [
            "v57.0",
            7.36
          ],
          [
            "v56.0",
            0.35
          ],
          [
            "v55.0",
            0.11
          ],
          [
            "v54.0",
            0.1
          ],
          [
            "v52.0",
            0.95
          ],
          [
            "v51.0",
            0.15
          ],
          [
            "v50.0",
            0.1
          ],
          [
            "v48.0",
            0.31
          ],
          [
            "v47.0",
            0.12
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Internet Explorer",
        id: "Internet Explorer",
        data: [
          [
            "v11.0",
            6.2
          ],
          [
            "v10.0",
            0.29
          ],
          [
            "v9.0",
            0.27
          ],
          [
            "v8.0",
            0.47
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Safari",
        id: "Safari",
        data: [
          [
            "v11.0",
            3.39
          ],
          [
            "v10.1",
            0.96
          ],
          [
            "v10.0",
            0.36
          ],
          [
            "v9.1",
            0.54
          ],
          [
            "v9.0",
            0.13
          ],
          [
            "v5.1",
            0.2
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Edge",
        id: "Edge",
        data: [
          [
            "v16",
            2.6
          ],
          [
            "v15",
            0.92
          ],
          [
            "v14",
            0.4
          ],
          [
            "v13",
            0.1
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Opera",
        id: "Opera",
        data: [
          [
            "v50.0",
            0.96
          ],
          [
            "v49.0",
            0.82
          ],
          [
            "v12.1",
            0.14
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: The drilldown functionality is designed to work only for the one axis. For using it in dual axes some custom changes will be required. Could you explain how it should look like in your opinion?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel - I was hoping that we should only see the series(es) that we are drilling down to not the level-1 series as you can see in the dual x,y axis jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p6cz7Lk1/1/

Comment: To fix it you need `hide` and `show` the unwanted series - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z0yhcjk7/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel It seems to work for specific use case. But will not fully support the kind of generic implementation I need.But as per my question your solution seems the most correct one as there are no other options for workaround of this issue. [Github issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6505)